# Nested objects in Json

Tags: json

I am a newbie in Json objects and Json array. I want to access a nested object in Json object , but I am making a slight error ,I have wasted my 2 hr searching also reading lots of stackoverflow's questions on it but I can't find where i am making an error. Please help me out

**Response**

```
{ __v: 0,
friends_in:
[ { friends_in_email: '12',
   friends_in_gcm_regId: '12'
} ]    
}
```

My code

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
```

Output:

```
{
"__v": " 0",
"friends_in": [
    {
        "friends_in_email": "12",
        "friends_in_gcm_regId": "12"
    }
   ]
}
```

Here is error generating saying **undefined**

MyCode

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(doc[0].__v));
console.log(JSON.stringify(doc[0].friends_in));
```

Output

```
0 //Correct
undefined //Why ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your stringified JSON (maybe some mistakes in pasting?). But using the below JSON, everything works as expected.

```
var rawString = '{ "__v":" 0", "friends_in": [{ "friends_in_email": "12", "friends_in_gcm_regId": "12"}] }';
var x = JSON.parse(rawString);
console.log(JSON.stringify(x.__v));
console.log(JSON.stringify(x.friends_in));
```

The above results in the following output:

```
0
[{"friends_in_email":"12","friends_in_gcm_regId":"12"}]
```

You seem to be mixing up JSON object (things in curly braces { ... }) and JSON arrays (things in square brackets [ ... ]). Only JSON arrays should be indexed like you have:

```
var y = [22, 24, 28]; 
y[0] // do something with it ...
```

Objects should have their members accessed by name:

```
var z = { test: 22, another_number: 24 }; 
z.test // do something with it ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot , i saw you have used JSON.parse() which is used in parsing a JSON, this helped me accessing "friends_in_email"